# SSH to Openshift server fails

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

I am working with jboss catridge on a openshift server. I am looking to share this instance with another person and added the other user' s public key(id_rsa.pub). When the other person tries to access the instance he is getting the error below. I tried them same with his instance and I am seeing the same error. What is the best way to share code with the openshift instance and synching the code between developers. Al this point we dont have a private Github repo. Please advise.

```
2013-02-09 14:37:47 Connecting to 54.234.36.245 port 22
2013-02-09 14:37:47 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
2013-02-09 14:37:47 Using SSH protocol version 2
2013-02-09 14:37:47 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.61
2013-02-09 14:37:47 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2013-02-09 14:37:47 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Host key fingerprint is:
2013-02-09 14:37:51 ssh-rsa 2048 cf:ee:77:cb:0e:fc:02:d7:72:7e:ae:80:c0:90:88:a7
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
2013-02-09 14:37:51 GSSAPI authentication request refused
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Access denied
2013-02-09 14:37:51 Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got this to work by:

1. Adding my converted key(.ppk file) from puttygen to pagent.
2. Accessing the git url that is defined in the openshift server using putty.

Both ssh and git access are working correctly now.

Comment: it is been more than 3 years yet the first solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GSSAPI for authentication, your system and the server must have it enabled. Based on your error message, this appears to be the last attempted form of authentication before failure.

Comment: I am using openshift console to add the key on the server. The server is a shared instance so I can access the server only with my login which does not have the permissions to the login. I am using putty in windows to login to the openshift instance. I disbled GSSAPI and now I get the error messages - Offered public key
Server refused public key
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Comment: errors when I tried ssh -v user@app-url debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).