# Can not SSH to openshift

Tags: ssh, openshift

I have problem with accessing SSH to Openshift.
I still can push code to Openshift via Git. But when trying to SSH to Openshift, the server denied with error "no supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic". I'm using Windows 7.

Do you know what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: contact their support?

Comment: stop by #openshift on freenode irc (https://webchat.freenode.com) and we'll get you fixed up.

Comment: I have posted on IRC but there's no response :(

Comment: Thang, next time you're on IRC, send me a private message on IRC and leave me your login and app name.  My irc nick is pmorie - I think we have a timezone mismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is for Windows users.
Who used puttygen.exe to generate your RSA keys.
And you added the PUBLIC key to your Openshift account, via the web console.
And you can PUTTY in OK, but not SSH from GIT-BASH (or cannot git clone via SSH).

One common reason is the key generated by puttygen.exe, is a PUTTY specific file.
You can convert this to OPENSSH format, from within the puttygen.exe program.
(Menu > Conversions > Export OpenSSH Key)
Save it to a new file, in the same directory as your original PUTTY generated PUBLIC/PRIVATE key pair.

Reference this OPENSSH key from your ~/.ssh/config file.
See step 4 here, if you dont have this config file.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Test by opening GIT-BASH, and trying your specific "ssh user@yourhost.rhcloud.com" (without the quotes, and where user and your host are specific to your account).  If that works, you should be good to go...

Comment: I mentioned my openssh format key in `~/.ssh/config`, and I can connect from both putty and git bash (`ssh my-user@my-openshift-domain`).
but `rhc ssh my-app-name` still gets  `FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Short version:
remove the leading "ssh " from the ssh url provided by the OpenShift web console.

I was frustrated when this happened to me. I tried all things mentioned above. At last I gave up in windows 7 and opened my Ubuntu virtual machine. Then I noticed the leading "ssh " in the url.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using Windows 7 and I had the same problem.

I created ssh keys with rhc tool and then public key for putty (id_rsa.ppk). Their permissions (GIT Bash, "ls -l" command) were 700 (but I couldn't connect):

```
-rwx------+ 1 User123 None 1706 Mar  4 19:46 id_rsa
-rwx------+ 1 User123 None 1464 Mar  4 19:52 id_rsa.ppk
-rwx------+ 1 User123 None  394 Mar  4 19:46 id_rsa.pub
```

So I changed the permission (with *chmod* command) to 755:

```
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 User123 None 1706 Mar  4 19:46 id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 User123 None 1464 Mar  4 19:52 id_rsa.ppk
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 User123 None  394 Mar  4 19:46 id_rsa.pub
```

And then both git-bash and ssh from putty started working. I know that these are not the most secure permissions, but for me it's enough. It may also help to run git/putty as administrator, but I didn't try that.

Comment: But... Windows doesn't have permissions like that?

Comment: I did it in GIT Bash (Windows 7). I don't know it maps to Windows permissions, but it was definitely the one thing that helped.

Comment: Maybe you can add the direct command
$ chmod -v 755 id_rsa.ppk

In my case this doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: I've just used "chmod 775 id_rsa" for each file. If permissions are ok for you, then you might have other problem that is causing this error. Please try other answers below and above. I hope you'll find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reach look into what the OpenShift forums provided on [no supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/permission-denied-publickeygssapi-keyexgssapi-with-mic-with-win-7-0). The Red Hat Customer Portal also has a good [article](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/500253) on this error, however you will need a [Silver](https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing) plan to see this article.

Typically, on linux this error is caused because the key you are using does not have the right permissions. In short your **.ssh/id_rsa** key's permissions are too lax (they should be [600](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php)).

Note that other people have seen [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792747/ssh-to-openshift-server-fails) issues related to this error with OpenShift so permissions may not be the root cause of your particular issue.

Comment: I think that my problems is a little bit difference. I still can using GIT to clone and push to the Openshift server. Just can't access SSH.

Answer (score 1):

go to preference in eclipse and in ssh key menu, click KEY MANAGEMENT and ther is a rsa key tab click that and copy your public key and click the button save as private key... then go to your open shift application and paste your public key and work  on it... i hope it working

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://2017-sparkler.rhcloud.com/2017/01/27/how-to-set-up-ssh-from-scratch-for-windows/)

### TOOLS

We will need two tools to work with :

1. PuTTY
2. PuTTYgen

### METHOD

**Step 1:** Generate a brand-new `SSH-2 RSA` key.

**Step 2:** Add the generated key in the `host` (for ex. in `settings  >> keys` on Openshift) that requires the authentication.

**Step 3:** Export this key from `PuTTYgen Conversions >> Export OpenSSH Key` and save it on your file-system

**Step 4:** Add/Edit your `~/.ssh/config file`

```
// ~/.ssh/config
Host HOST_NAME // for example - https://my-domain.rhcloud.com
  Port PORT_NUMBER // ideally 22
  IdentityFile PATH/TO/FILE/CREATED/IN/STEP/3 // the path to where the key was exported
```

### Example Configuration of `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host cool-websites.rhcloud.com
 Port 22
 IdentityFile C:/Users/cool_dude/Desktop/rhcloud
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create keys in Puttygen -  https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe. Format - SSH-2 RSA.
This keys have correct format. It works.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Linux users. If you have the same problem, disabling GSSAPI may help.

Edit your `~/.ssh/config` (user) or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (system-wide) file to set `GSSAPIAuthentication no`.

Source: [Speed up SSH logon by disabling GSSAPIAuthentication](https://coderwall.com/p/fukoew/speed-up-ssh-logon-by-disabling-gssapiauthentication)

> Connecting the SSH servers can sometimes be delayed when the client
>   and server try to sort out if they should be using GSSAPI to
>   authenticate.