# Permission denied when connecting to OpenShift SSH

Tags: ssh, openshift

Whenever I try to `git clone` or `ssh` into my application, I get `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`. Already tried PuTTY, re-generating the key with `rhc setup`, `ssh-keygen`, Putty Keygen, nothing worked.

Anyone help is extremely appreciated.

I've been looking at all (~20) similar questions on StackOverflow, and none of those helped me out.

Comment: It looks like you've tried a few things already, but it may be worth listing the answers you've tried to no avail not to get them repeated here. Based on what you mentioned, you can try `ssh-add` ([FAQ reference](https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_why_am_i_getting_a_permission_denied_error)), check that the correct key is uploaded using the web interface and [the permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22181220/5400813).

Comment: I have tried removing all keys, adding them back with ssh-add, rhc setup, the permissions thing did not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 week after: it starts working. Guess it was just pacience? Whatever, thanks everyone.